# call jsp for autosuggestion search box by selecting column of database in dropdown list

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want a autosuggestion searchbox which search things from database.I have a feature of selecting by which column user search bu providing dropdownlist of database columns.For one column its working fine.But as I select another column,it search both the first selected column and the second just selected column.
I want not so.Make me out of it
Here is is code.It has mvc design pattern.
**Index.html**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("#country").autocomplete("find.me", {
          extraParams: {
            choice: function() { 
              return $("#searchby").val();
            }
          }
        });
});
    </script>
       <div>


 Search By:
  <select name="searchby" id="searchby" >
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="roll_no">Roll No</option>
  <option value="city">City</option>
      <option value="pin_code">Pin Code</option>
      <option value="state">State</option>
      <option value="country">Country</option>
      </select>
     </div>
        <span class="input input--nariko">

          <input id="country" class="input__field input__field--nariko" type="text" id="input-20" name="country" />
          <label class="input__label input__label--nariko" for="input-20">
            <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--nariko">Type Something</span>
          </label>
        </span>
```

**Servlet Controller**

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String searchBy=request.getParameter("choice");

    String[] arr=new AutoCompleteDao().autoComplete(searchBy);

 request.setAttribute("arr", arr);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("list.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

**Dao Class AutocompleteDao.java**
     public class AutoCompleteDao {
    private static final String DRIVER_NAME="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    private static final String DB_NAME="autotest";

```
private static final String USER_NAME="root";
private static final String PASSWORD="WELcome@123";
Connection connection;


public String[] autoComplete(String searchBy){
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;

    String query=null;
    try{
        //Register JDBC Driver
        Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME).newInstance();
        //open a connection
        connection=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(URL+DB_NAME,USER_NAME,PASSWORD);
          switch(searchBy){
           case "name":
              query= "SELECT name FROM test";
               break;
           case "country":
               query="SELECT country FROM test";
               break;
           }

        stmt=(PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);

     resultSet= stmt.executeQuery();
       List li = new ArrayList();




       while(resultSet.next())
       {
           li.add(resultSet.getString(1));
       }


    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(InstantiationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IllegalAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
            if(connection!=null)
                connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

return li.toArray(new String[li.size()]);
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>AutoCompleteServlet</servlet-name>
  <servletclass>AutoCompleteServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AutoCompleteServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/find.me</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And list.jsp which is displaying result
**List.jsp**

```
   <%String[] str=null;
str=(String[])request.getAttribute("arr"); 
if(str!=null){
//jQuery related start
String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");

int cnt=1;
for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
{
    if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
    {%>

       <%=str[j] %>

<%    } 
}
str=null;
//jQuery related end
}
%>
```

Here when i select name from dropdownlist and type in autosuggesstion it shows name from database when there is a match found.But when I select country.
It shows i.e. suggest both country and name from database.
I really cant understand why?

Comment: No its not.When I select country after I select name first time.It shows both entries @YuliiaChuhui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is only run once, onload:

```
$("#country").autocomplete("find.me",{extraParams: {choice: end}} );
```

At this point `end` is the empty-string, and that'll work its way through to the back-end and hit the `default` case in the `autoComplete` method in `AutocompleteDao.java`, which does auto-complete by name.

You don't say which autocomplete plugin you're using, but you *might* be able to do something like:

```
$("#country").autocomplete("find.me", {
  extraParams: {
    choice: function() { 
      return $("#searchby").val();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: sir When i select name first time it is showing correct i.e. name in autosuggestion box.But now when i select country from dropdown menu ,now it calls servlet "find.me" two times very quickly

Comment: Ok you say it will default call by name from backend.But when i select only country next time without refreshing page from dropdownlist menu it suggest both name and country

Comment: Reverse is true. First time when I select country, it shows country only. After this when I select name from dropdownlist it shows name and country this time also

Comment: You may have a thread-safety issue in `AutocompleteDao.java` as `str` isn't a method-local variable.  You could try using `return li.toArray(new String[li.size()])` instead of manually converting the list to an array yourself.

Comment: Can you update the question with the real code for `AutocompleteDao.java` - the current version in the question doesn't compile (`DriverManager.getConnection` throws a `SQLException` which the version in the question doesn't catch or declare...)

Comment: I have made changes in index.html of jquery as you said.I also have made changes in dao as you said. and i uploaded the complete dao . But the problem remains same

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using?

Do you know how to use your browsers developer tools? (usually right-click and select 'Inspect' or 'Inspect Element', or hit F12 in Internet Explorer.)

I think we need to confirm the front-end is working by using browser developer tools to check the server request actually includes a 'choice' parameter with a value.  After that, we can move onto the back-end and see where the problems are with the Servlet and DAO.

Is your `AutocompleteDao` `System.out.println` outputting '0 SELECT name FROM test' or '0 SELECT country FROM test'?

Comment: No no its just was checking. Zero has no meaning there.As u said about developer tool, I am on it. But I dont understand what i check there? And I have edit it ie project dao @searlea

Comment: As you say: it's just checking. Is it showing 'name' or 'country'? Which autocomplete library are you using? In the browser developer tools you would use the network panel to confirm the parameters being submitted by the autocomplete library.